# WebGL why elongated objects size

Tags: javascript, glsl, webgl

I'm using webgl and my objects look incorrect - they length in z-size much bigger than it should be

[image: HOW SHOULDN'T LOOK]

In the picture right cube in the top is so long, why does it happen?
My MVPmatrix looks like:

```
var y = Math.tan(fovy / 2);
    var x = y / ratio;
    var d = 1;
    var out = new Mat4([
        x, 0, 0, 0,
        0, y, 0, 0,
        0, 0, (far + near) / (far - near), d,
        0, 0, -2 * (far * near) / (far - near), 0
    ]);
```

Shader for cubes:

```
`#define MAX_POINTLIGHTS 16

        attribute vec3 a_Position;
        attribute vec3 a_Normal;

        uniform mat4 u_MVMatrix;
        uniform mat4 u_MVPMatrix;
        uniform mat3 u_MVNMatrix;
        uniform vec3 u_PointLights[MAX_POINTLIGHTS];

        varying float v_Light;

        void main(void) {
            vec4 position4 = u_MVMatrix * vec4(a_Position, 1.0);
            vec3 position3 = position4.xyz / position4.w;

            float light = 0.0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
                vec3 lightDir = normalize(u_PointLights[0] - position3);
                vec3 normal = normalize(u_MVNMatrix * a_Normal);

                light += max(dot(normal, lightDir), 0.0);
            }
            v_Light = min(light, 1.0);

            gl_Position = u_MVPMatrix * position4;
        }`,

        `precision mediump float;

        uniform vec4 u_DiffuseColor;

        varying float v_Light;

        void main(void) {
            gl_FragColor = vec4(u_DiffuseColor.rgb * v_Light, u_DiffuseColor.a);
        }`
```

I really haven't ideas. I have old engine and I did it well, so this 2 projects no barely no differents in code, but it doesn't work in new one.
Does you have any ideas? Big thanks!

Comment: did you set the viewport?

Comment: Yes, when clearing scene

Comment: I think I found a problem: field of vision was on 90 degrees instead < 60 degs.